# How do I set the toggle state in a foreach loop in SwiftUI

Tags: binding, toggle, swiftui

When I try to set show a toggle inside a loop of value from a dictionary, I get very little help from the error message.

If I un-comment the 3 lines of commented code below, trying to add a toggle for each of the properties in the loop, I get the following error:

Cannot convert value of type 'HStack, Text, ConditionalContent)>>' to closure result type '_'

```
import SwiftUI

struct properties {
    var id : Int
    var property : String
    var isOn : Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var propertyValues: [properties] = [properties(id: 1, property: "DemoData", isOn: true),
                                                 properties(id: 2, property: "ShowLocalEvents", isOn: false)]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(propertyValues.identified(by: \.id)) { propertyValue in
                        HStack {
//                            Toggle(isOn: propertyValue.isOn) {
//                                Text("")
//                            }
                            Text("\(propertyValue.property)")
                            if propertyValue.isOn {
                                Text("On")
                            } else {
                                Text("Off")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is that the initializer `Toggle(isOn:label:)` takes a `Binding<Bool>` for its `isOn` parameter rather than just a `Bool`. A `Binding<_>` is sort of a readable-writable "view" into a property that allows a control to update a value that it doesn't own and have those changes propagate out to whoever *does* own the property.

EDIT: I made this more complicated than it needed to be. The following works:

```
ForEach($propertyValues.identified(by: \.id.value)) { (propertyValue: Binding<properties>) in
    HStack {
        Toggle(isOn: propertyValue.isOn) {
            Text("")
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

By using a `$propertyValues`, we are accessing a `Binding` to the array itself, which is transformed into bindings to each of the elements.

EDIT:

For the above to work, you'll need to add `.value` in a couple places in the body so that you are referring to the actual values and not the bindings to the values.

Comment: Thanks for the additions on the Binding and the comment about value. Works well now.

Comment: But then how I can access propertyValue.property? ex. 

`ForEach($propertyValues.identified(by: \.id.value)) { (propertyValue: Binding<properties>) in
    HStack {
        Toggle(isOn: propertyValue.isOn) {
            Text(propertyValue.property)
        }
        // ...
    }
}`

Comment: @user1366265 You should be able to access `propertyValue.property.value`.

Comment: @Jumhyn I'm still struggling with this a bit, I'm getting "Unable to infer closure type in the current context" `ForEach ($thisCardData, id: \.self) { (card: Binding<ICard>) in`

thisCardData is of type [ICard] which is Identifiable, so I'm not sure I need the id: part of that ForEach statement.

Comment: I do get this error... Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'Binding<[properties]>' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'. what is that?

Answer (score 1):

Accepted solution didn't work for me, or it changed during the years, this one does, with less confusing names:

```
struct Object: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var isOn: Bool
}
ForEach($objects) { ($obj: Binding<Object>) in
    Toggle(obj.title, isOn: $obj.isOn)
}
```